# Lenses on older canon bodies only shows up as focal range in Lightroom. Can this be fixed?

Tags: canon, lightroom, metadata

When using some of my older Canon bodies such as the 1Ds and the 1Ds mk II, the lenses only shows up as the focal range in the metadata when imported to lightroom. For example the Canon EF 24-105/4,0 L IS USM only shows up as "24.0-105.0 mm" instead of "Canon EF24-105 mm f/4 IS USM" as it does on newer bodies. This makes things difficult when for example keeping macro and wide primes sharing the focal lenght apart. It also means that the same lens is sorted under two different ones depending on body used. The latest firmwares for the bodies has not solved the issue.

Is there a solution to this issue? It would be great if the lens shows up correctly and the lens correction still could be applied automatically if needed and not involving me having to find it in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to introduce this capability into a camera body that doesn't have it. My Canon XT/350D was the same way.

You may have to resort to batch-editing the EXIF information after-the-fact with a plugin like [LensTagger](http://www.essl.de/wp/software/lenstagger-lightroom-plugin/).